# Windows 8 mail app not showing subscribe/unsubscribe hyperlink?

Tags: html, email, windows-8, hyperlink, windows-8-mail-app

I am working on a Wordpress Plugin in which i am sending email by using PHP mail function. In email body I am making a hyperlink. I am checking sent email in Windows 8 Mail App. In email I don't see hyperlink it's only plain text. Why is this happening?
I'm using following code for email:

```
ini_set("include_path", ".:/PHPMailer_5.2.4/");
        require_once("../../../PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
        global $wpdb;
        $to = "Receiver email";  // change this address with yours
        $subject = "subject";
        $name="name";
        $from="name@domain.com";

    $message = "<p>Please <a href='www.domain.com/unsubscribe.php?".$to."' target='_blank' onclick='unsubscribe_js($to);'>click here</a> to unsubscribe, if you don't want to getting more emails from us.</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host     = "mail.domain.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "user@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "Password";
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->From     = $from;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->Send();
```

I made "click here" as hyperlink but it is shown as plain text in windows 8 mail app. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: That's not a valid hyperlink.  Where's the `http://`?

Comment: @aksu : kindly check and tell that if hyper links in the mails sent by this script is not working in the windows 8 mail app or any hyperlinks (in other mails ) are also not showing up.Cos there seems to be an issue with the mail app.

Comment: @Shiva Some of the links in the emails are working some aren't. It could be some bug in the mail app but i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting $mail->IsHTML(true); ?

Comment: yes i tried it but not works.click here is still seems like plain text not as a link .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes in the html tags and using single quotes as string delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more of Mail app's bug to me rather than the script's bug because I found some other articles on the net([link1](http://www.eightforums.com/browsers-mail/11072-hyperlinks-stopped-working-windows-8-mail-app.html) ,[link2](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-8/247936-8-1-built-email-app-hyperlinks.html) etc.) that mention the problem but in different scenarios .

I would like to mention the solution I rather found on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/543ef29a-0004-4ac9-84fb-bd99fd3b2d92/windows-8-mail-apps-hyperlink-not-working), for you to try.

```
1. open regedit
2. delete 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID' key. (You may need to do a backup before killing it.)
3. reboot.
```

don't worry if there are a lot of keys in `CLSID`, they will be recreated on reboot. Hope this solution helps.